# Visualization of pictures for points in QGIS

Tags: qgis, kml, import

I'm working with QGIS Desktop 3.2.3.

A Colleague of mine worked on a Google Map and inserted in his Google Map Pictures. He exported the KML and gave it to me so that I can import it to QGIS.

The pictures are part of the attribute table as a URL. Is it possible to download the pictures into QGIS?

Comment: Do you want to visualise the picture of each feature when using the identify button or do you want to download all the linked pictures? Your title question and the body of the question don't seem to agree on that.

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming you have a point layer, with a photo URL specified in an attribute for each point, and want to display that photo at the respective point in the map.

In the symbology for that layer, make it Single Symbol with a Raster Image Marker as the symbol layer type. Underneath, where you would expect to specify the path of a single image to use for all point, instead at the right choose Data Driven Override, and specify the attribute with the URL as the variable. I believe for some time now this would work if the field contained a (fully qualified) local filename to the photo, but I have just tested and in QGIS 3.6 it allows also a remote URL, not only a filename.

You'll need to set an appropriate symbol size, in display or map units. Here it's 10mm. The bottom 2 photos are local files on my harddrive, the top one a web image via URL.

[image: Example with 3 images]

If your attribute is not a fully qualified URL or filename, you can use the expression editor in the data driven override to add a prefix as necessary, etc., eg. `'c:\\pathname\\'+"Photo Name"` or `'http://website/'+"Photo Name"` (note the doubled backslashes to escape them).

Comment: Rereading and noting you say you're using version 3.2.3. I think references to local files should work there (not sure) but that you'll need 3.6 to use an URL.

Comment: where do I find the Raster Image Marker please? I am using QGIS 3.8. Thank you

Comment: @Petr Symbology / Single Symbol then create a new symbol layer (or change an existing one) with Symbol layer type -- first item i the dialog below the symbol layer tree -- set to Raster Image Marker

Comment: Thank you, I manage to do that. I just wonder if it is possible in case the photos are overlapping to move them around? Because with fixed positions they ovelap each other.

Answer (score -1):

If instead you want to browse the photos in a separate window, marking the appropriate point on the map, take a look at the `eVis` plug-in, described for instance in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RB469GYcI7k