# Importing animated GIFs in QGIS

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, qgis-2, import, animation

Is it possible to import a animated GIF into QGIS? And is it also possible to georeference it, to have it on the right place?

Comment: What happens when you drag and drop it to the map?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visualization of pictures for points in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/314017/visualization-of-pictures-for-points-in-qgis)

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: Have drag and dropped it, but doesnt work.....

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you load a gif into QGIS as a raster you can use a World File to locate it geographically.

Since its world unicorn day, here's a Unicorn GIF loaded into QGIS:

[image]

note that it will not animate. The image is loaded as a raster with 80 bands. I think each band is a frame of animation but you'd have to play with it to make it animate. What I've shown is a single band rendered as gray-scale.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try that. Read now, that the addon Time Manager could also be a solution;-)