# How to display image from SQLite database at each point? (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, symbology, attribute-table, visualisation, dbmanager

How do I display images at specific points, through the raster image marker symbology, from a standalone BLOB attribute table (SQLite) loaded into QGIS?

To briefly summarise: I have loaded a SQLite database and a geopackage database into QGIS. This geopackage database contains points spread over all of Denmark, containing information like GNSS station names, gps nr, coordinates, height measurements etc.

Then, as a supplement to these points, I have this SQLite database that contains images tied to each point. The SQLite database loads in fine, and can join layers with the geopackage database. But I can't seem to figure out how to display the images tied to each point.

So far, I've managed to display a custom image that I loaded down from Google at each point, through the raster image marker, roughly following this guide:
[Guide to adding pictures through raster image marker](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/314017/visualization-of-pictures-for-points-in-qgis)

But I want to load the images from the database (geo_ref skitse) that has unique images tied to each point instead, which is a bit more tricky.

I have made 2 screendumps of how my situation looks as of now, if that is of any help.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It's very easy with the help of the Expression String builder. See my example, where I use the following expression to display the PNG images from my Geopackage table "images":

> 'base64:'||to_base64( attribute(get_feature( 'images','name',concat( 'Wappen_',"bl")),'image'))

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

To use Raster image markers:

Choose Single Symbol
Change Symbol label type from Simple marker to Raster image marker
Use a Data-defined override for the file location
Field type: string → photo (string)
[image]

I snagged this from here:
https://bnhr.xyz/2019/09/22/geotagged-photos-in-qgis.html